# Run stored procedure as username determined at deployment time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Similar to [Can you set a stored procedure to always execute as a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260929/can-you-set-a-stored-procedure-to-always-execute-as-a-specific-user)

How can you set 'domain/username' to a value determined at deployment time?  The username could be different per environment, and I can read a local table to get the service username.

```
DECLARE @ServiceUsername
SELECT @ServiceUsername = [val] FROM [ConfigTable] WHERE ...
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spMyProc
WITH EXECUTE AS @ServiceUsername    /* fails. expects literal string */
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work exactly like your asking. When you run `EXECUTE AS` onto a stored procedure, that configuration is part of the stored procedure compilation, so it can't be dynamically tied to a variable.

If you convert your `CREATE PROC` statements into an NVARCHAR, then you can run the `sp_dynamicsql` to compile the specific stored proc with the configured username.

**Update with sample**

Here's a quick work-up I did on my local instance. I ran the code while connected via windows auth, but used dynamic sql to create the proc forcing it to execute as my local SQL account. The proc is simple in that it just outputs the user running the proc to confirm the execution context.

```
-- Connected with windows auth (domain/jason)
DECLARE @Username VARCHAR(100) = 'jasonw'
DECLARE @SP NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    CREATE PROC dbo.spMyProc
    WITH EXECUTE AS ''__EXEC_AS_USER__''
    AS
    BEGIN
        PRINT USER_NAME() -- Do work here
    END'
SET @SP = REPLACE(@SP, '__EXEC_AS_USER__', @Username)
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SP
EXEC dbo.spMyProc
```

This code correctly outputs `jasonw` (local SQL account) instead of my windows account.

Comment: Right I'm not trying to have the stored procedure dynamically tied to a variable, just to have the "WITH EXECUTE AS aaaaa" clause populated from a variable so that when the script is run, the value is read from the configuration database and the resultant string is used as the value completing the clause.

Comment: @RobertKerr -  I just updated the answer to show sample code on how to accomplish what I think your described above. Hopefully this will help!