# Get full capacity of a disk via SQL query without granting permissions?

Tags: sql-server

I've been struggling to get the total capacity of a disk drive where SQL Server is installed; I know I can achieve that with `sys.dm_os_volume_stats` or `xp_cmdshell` but to run the query you need some permissions like `VIEW SERVER STATE` or `ALTER permission`.

Is there a way for a normal user to get the full capacity of the disk without granting special permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Execute any Stored Procedure or Table Value Function as a specific caller :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
WITH EXECUTE AS 'domain\user'
AS
...
```

[More info in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260929/can-you-set-a-stored-procedure-to-always-execute-as-a-specific-user)

[More info in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Also, If you got a Certificate problem :

[Signing Stored Procedures with a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)